# Linux: how to check if a drive is mount to nfs

Tags: linux, nfs

Is there a way to find out if a mount drive, for ex: /var, is mount to an NFS?

Comment: If you run the shell command "mount" it tells you what filesystem the drive is.

Comment: [`df -PT /var | awk 'NR==2 {print $2}'`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72223/check-if-folder-is-a-mounted-remote-filesystem)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can just use `mount` command to check, e.g

```
mount |grep nfs
```

Or if you want to list all nfs you've mounted:

```
mount -l -t nfs4
```